# How to make Google Sheets REGEXTRACT RegEx function do "greedy" pattern matching

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I'm trying to build a pattern to select "**1.2.**" from "**1.2.3**" (i.e. select every digit and dot before the last digit group) to work in `REGEXEXTRACT` sheet function in *Google Sheets*.

I came up with the pattern `^([0-9]+\.)+` which presumably corresponds to both [*Perl*](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html) and [*Google/re2*](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) specification. So, my code is:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("1.2.3";"^([0-9]+\.)+")
```

I tested it on https://regexr.com/ where it returns "**1.2.**"
and on https://regex101.com/ where it returns "**1.2.**" as the whole result and "**2.**" as group 1.

But on *Google Sheets*, it returns "**2.**" only.

I think that it is connected to either:

1. "*ungreedy*" evaluation by `REGEXEXTRACT` (which is contrary to *Google/re2* specification;
2. the above plus it returns only *the first group*;

I tried a way-around, so to make good of item 2 above. So, I changed the pattern to `(^([0-9]+\.)+)`.
I tested it on https://regexr.com/ where it returns "**1.2.**"
and on https://regex101.com/ where it returns "**1.2.**" as the whole result and as group 1.
Unfortunately, it triggers `#REF!` error in *Google Sheets*.

So, my questions - what is the way to make *greedy* selection of the longest possible substring in *Google Sheets* or a way-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=regexextract("1.2.3","^([0-9.]+)[^\.]+$")
```

or, reference the cell with the string "1.2.3"

```
=regexextract(A2, "^([0-9.]+)[^\.]+$")
```

Comment: The practical side of the question is solved.  
The theoretical one remains - why Google Sheets doesn't use (or how it make use) a greedy mode, which is default according to Google/re2.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("1.2.3", "^\d+.\d+.")
```

Comment: I think this would work; the answer could do with some explanation though.

Comment: Thank you! This works for the example I gave.My actual task is a little bit more difficult, Numbering can be nested